# how to redirect multiline bash command into a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to redirect this command to a variable:

```
{
    printf 'scan on\n\n'
    sleep 10
    printf 'quit \n\n'  
} | bluetoothctl
```

I tried to do this:

```
variable=$(printf 'scan on\n\n' sleep 10 printf 'quit \n\n' | bluetoothctl)
echo $variable
```

but I am getting blank output. I also tried to split it:

```
variable=$(printf 'scan on\n\n' | bluetoothctl)
sleep 10
printf 'quit \n\n'| bluetoothctl
echo $variable
```

but this time I only get

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# quit
```

**How do I redirect the output of the first command which is printed to `stdout` when you run it, into a variable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is the lack of semicolons (that are otherwise equivalent to newlines).  And if you want to see the structure of the output, add double-quotes.  Try:

```
variable=$( { printf 'scan on\n\n' ; sleep 10 ; printf 'quit \n\n' ; } | bluetoothctl)
echo "$variable"
```

Answer (score 7):

Just:

```
variable=$(
  {
    printf 'scan on\n\n'
    sleep 10
    printf 'quit \n\n'  
  } | bluetoothctl
)
```

The inside of command substitutions can be any shell code¹ and doesn't have to be on one line.

Here, you want to capture the output of the whole pipeline (in effect, that will be the output of `bluetoothctl` since all the other commands have their stdout redirected to the pipe that goes to `bluetoothctl`).

You could also capture the output of `bluetoothctl` only with:

```
{
  printf 'scan on\n\n'
  sleep 10
  printf 'quit \n\n'  
} | variable=$(bluetoothctl)
```

But in `bash`, for that to work, you'd need to set the `lastpipe` option (`shopt -s lastpipe`, only works for non-interactive shell instances), for that last pipe component *not* to be run in a subshell.

Here however, you don't need the pipeline, you can just do:

```
variable=$(bluetoothctl --timeout 10 scan on)
```

If you're going to display the contents of the variable, remember the syntax is:

```
printf '%s\n' "$variable"
```

not <strike>`echo $variable`</strike>.

More details on that at:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Here the output of `bluetoothctl` contains colouring escape sequences as well as escape sequences used to clear the contents of lines. If you leave `$variable` unquoted, its contents will be subject to split+glob resulting in a random list of words to pass to `echo` which `echo` will output space-separated. So you'll end up with everything on one line and if the last word ends in a *clear-line* sequence (which it does in my tests: `\r\e[K` being *Carriage-Return* followed by the *Clear-To-End-Of-Line* sequence), you'll just see a blank line.

---

<sup>¹ though some shells including `bash` used to choke on code with unmatched parenthesis  like when the code included case statements like `case $x in foo)` or comments with unbalanced `)` which the shell parser was mistaking for the `)` closing the command substitution.</sup>

Comment: for the first one I get the blank one again. For the second one I am getting the ouput only if I execute `shopt -s lastpipe` before it, but output is missing on some places and is weirdly only on one line. I don't know if I did something wrong

Comment: @cheshire, probably down to you using `echo $variable` instead of `printf '%s\n' "$variable"`. See [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: You were right. Just one more question, is there some problem in simply doing it like the answer that I accepted suggests?

Comment: @cheshire, whether you use `;` or `newline` to separate the command substitutions will not make any difference in that case. Whether using `echo` will cause problem or not in that case depends on a number of parameters detailed in the Q&A I linked to. Using `echo` to output arbitrary data is bad practice in general.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative could be a simple `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn bluetoothctl

send "scan on\r"

sleep 10

send "quit \r"

expect eof
```

`\r`  equals "Return / pressing enter". Make executable and run.

Comment: I guess it could be good idea, but I am not familiar with manipulating output or storing it in `expect`